JavaScript event deprecated on function with parameters
I was given two functions that are nearly identical, but one uses a parameter.
function handleBlur() {
  const list = event.currentTarget.closest("#nav ul");
  if (!event.relatedTarget || !list.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    closeNav();
  }
}

function handleDropdownBlur(btn) {
  const list = event.currentTarget.closest("#nav ul");
  if (!event.relatedTarget || !list.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    closeDropdown(btn);
  }
}

I was able to change the first function to work properly by simply adding event as the function parameter.
function handleBlur(event) {
  const list = event.currentTarget.closest("#nav ul");
  if (!event.relatedTarget || !list.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    closeNav();
  }
}

How would I change the second function to not warn of deprecation?
I tried adding event as both a first and second parameter, but this breaks the functionality.
The function is called later in the code like this:
dropdowns.forEach((dropdown) => {
  const list = dropdown.querySelectorAll("li a");
  list[list.length - 1].addEventListener("blur", (event) => {
    handleDropdownBlur(dropdown.previousElementSibling);
  });
});


Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to ask a good question. Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add all the relevant code so create a [mre].

You can use an anonymous function in addEventListener(): element.addEventListener('blur', event => handleDropdownBlur(event, btn))

What "doesn't work properly" about it?  How are you using it?  The function internally uses a variable called event, where does that come from if not a function parameter?

How is handleDropdownBlur used within your code?

@David probably the global event which exists in IE and Chrome. When an event handler executes the global event is assigned to the event parameter the function would get. IIRC, it was IE that started it forcing a really lazy and error prone code practices. Chrome adopted it for reasons unknown to me. And FF didn't adopt it which sounds sensible. I'm not sure if the landscape around the global event has changed in the past few years, though, EDIT: Is event a global variable that is accessible everywhere inside the callback chain?

If you do element.addEventListener('blur',handleBlur) then no need to pass an event. Please show the HTML or code where you assign handleBlur - likely inline which is not recommended

@mplungjan I updated the question to include how the function is called later in the code.

@garrett: Given the update... What exactly are you asking?  The function accepts one argument, and you're passing it one argument.  When you modify the function to accept another argument, do you pass another argument?  What problem do you encounter in the code you're showing us?

@David I'm being warned that event is deprecated.

@garrett: Voted to re-open.  The global event object is indeed deprecated.  However, an event object is already passed to the event listener.  You can pass that object to your function.

@3limin4t0r That caused the deprecation warning to go away. Thank you.

@3limin4t0r please post that as an answer now that the question has been reopened

Would be even better to see a [mcve] with relevant html. Whenever I see event handling using a loop, I recommend event delegation from the closest static container.

Your current function definition of handleDropdownBlur uses the global event variable, which is indeed deprecated.
Changing your code to:
dropdowns.forEach((dropdown) => {
  const list = dropdown.querySelectorAll("li a");
  list[list.length - 1].addEventListener("blur", (event) => {
    // accept the event object from addEventListener ^
    handleDropdownBlur(event, dropdown.previousElementSibling);
    // forward the event ^ to handleDropdownBlur
  });
});

Will forward the event object provided by addEventListener to handleDropdownBlur as the first argument. You then have to change the handleDropdownBlur definition to also accept this argument:
function handleDropdownBlur(event, btn) {
  // accept the event as first ^ argument
  const list = event.currentTarget.closest("#nav ul");
  if (!event.relatedTarget || !list.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    closeDropdown(btn);
  }
}

This doesn't have to be the first argument and could also be forward as the second, or any other argument for that matter. But it's common practice to let event always be the first argument with any additional data following it.

Forwarding the event by changing the function to function handleDropdownBlur(event, btn) and then calling the function using handleDropdownBlur(event, dropdown.previousElementSibling) fixed the deprecation warning and it works fine.
function handleDropdownBlur(event, btn) {
  const list = event.currentTarget.closest("#nav ul");
  if (!event.relatedTarget || !list.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    closeDropdown(btn);
  }
}

dropdowns.forEach((dropdown) => {
  const list = dropdown.querySelectorAll("li a");
  list[list.length - 1].addEventListener("blur", (event) => {
    handleDropdownBlur(event, dropdown.previousElementSibling);
  });
});


